# How Upload Files on Server using WebClient Windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8, upload, webclient

I want upload a file (any type) on a server.

I have my file which is saved like this (I use FileAssociation)

```cs
await SharedStorageAccessManager.CopySharedFileAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "fileToSave" + fileext, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, NavigationContext.QueryString["filetoken"]);
```

Then I get the saved file

```cs
                StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("fileToSave" + fileext);
                Stream data = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(file.Path, UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.Path);
                ServerFunctions.UploadFile(filename,data);
```

Then I start the Upload

```cs
 internal void UploadFile(string fileName,Stream data)
        {
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRequestParam.AuthentificationLogin))
            {
                System.Net.NetworkCredential account = new NetworkCredential(dataRequestParam.AuthentificationLogin, dataRequestParam.AuthentificationPassword);
                web.Credentials = account;
            }

            web.AllowReadStreamBuffering = true;
            web.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;


            web.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                PushData(data, e.Result);
                e.Result.Close();
                data.Close();

            };
            web.OpenWriteAsync(dataRequestParam.TargetUri,"POST");
        }

        private void PushData(Stream input, Stream output)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
```

The web server is supposed to send me as a response a xml with an error code or succes code inside. 
None error is thrown but it doesnt work.And I don't understand why the e.result is a stream object.  As I said the server should return a string...(xml file)

Could you bring me some explannations of what is happening in my code and if it will work with all types of files ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you intend to use this as a streaming protocol or did you want a discrete HTTP request from your client with a response from the server? It would seem to me from your phrasing that the latter is how you've implemented the server-side architecture, but your client code is not consuming it as a request/response transaction.

Comment: Yes I want request the server from my Windows phone client.I get inspired by this [code](https://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/file-upload-wp7-59702.aspx) So what are you suggesting ?

Comment: I think it may be a little easier to work with a WebRequest class instead of WebClient for what you're trying to do. I'll add an example momentarily.

Comment: Just as an aside, "Authentification" isn't a word. ;)

Comment: yes it is...a french word...yes I mix French and english in my code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem here is that you're attempting to get this to behave like a streaming protocol when it seems you intend a request/response type architecture. For those purposes, you should consider working with a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) object.

Bear with me as I fully qualify the namespace of the objects used inline, so it may get a little verbose, but I want you to know where to find these things.

```
internal async void UploadFile(string fileName, System.IO.Stream data)
{
    // Specify URI, method, and credentials for the request
    System.Net.WebRequest web = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(dataRequestParam.TargetUri);
    web.Method = "POST";

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRequestParam.AuthenticationLogin))
    {
        web.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(dataRequestParam.AuthenticationLogin, dataRequestParam.AuthenticationPassword);
    }

    // Create the request payload from the provided stream
    System.IO.Stream requestStream =
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.IO.Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(web.BeginGetRequestStream, web.EndGetRequestStream, null);
    await data.CopyToAsync(requestStream);

    // Get a response from the server
    System.Net.WebResponse response =
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(web.BeginGetResponse, web.EndGetResponse, null);

    // Possibly parse the response with an XmlReader (example only)
    System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream());
    string responseText = reader.ReadInnerXml(); // TODO: Real work here
}
```

The one oddity here is using the Task factory to create a task from the begin and end methods from getting both the request stream and the response. This makes it much simpler to consume these methods as you get a Task back which can be awaited for its return object, which you can then manipulate directly.

I'm not sure what form your response from the server takes on success versus failure, so I've simply shown how to create an XML reader to parse XML from the resulting stream. You can do whatever parsing is necessary yourself on these lines, but this should at least give you a look at what your server is returning in response.

Comment: I got a crash on the webresponse : read is not supported on the main thread when buffering is disabled. But i found a code which works thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The final code I use.

```cs
 WebRequest web = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(dataRequestParam.TargetUri);

               web.ContentType = dataRequestParam.ContentType;
               web.Method = "POST";
               web.ContentLength = data.Length;


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRequestParam.AuthentificationLogin))
                {
                    web.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(dataRequestParam.AuthentificationLogin, dataRequestParam.AuthentificationPassword);
                }


                using (var requestStream = await Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(web.BeginGetRequestStream, web.EndGetRequestStream, web))
                {
                    await data.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
                }


                WebResponse responseObject = await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(web.BeginGetResponse, web.EndGetResponse, web);
                var responseStream = responseObject.GetResponseStream();
                var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string received = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();

                return received;
            }
```